# I would like to create a loop to retrieve weather data from easyclimate

Tags: r

I'm working on a database of 101 stations measured every year from 1992 to the present day.
I'd like to extract weather data from the easyclimate database to complete my database. However, as the easyclimate data is daily, it's too large for R (I've tried and R can't reach the end of the query).

So I'd like to create a loop that retrieves the weather data for each year and averages it before doing the same for the following year.

```
stats %>% 
  left_join(List_st_Stream_Air_Temp,by="Code") %>% 
  select(-n)->clim


clim <- st_as_sf(clim, coords = c("X", "Y") ) %>%
  st_set_crs( 2154 ) %>%   #set coordinate system used
  st_transform( 4326 )

ann <-levels(as.factor(clim$Year))


# Initiation
coef_mod <- list()

# Starting the loop!
for (i in ann) {
  
  temperatures_i <- clim %>% 
    filter(Year==i)
  
daily <- get_daily_climate(temperatures_i, 
                             period = i, # years
                             climatic_var = c("Tmin","Tmax","Prcp"))

yearly <- daily %>% 
    group_by(Year, Code) %>% 
    summarise(Tmin_m = mean(Tmin),Tmax_m = mean(Tmax),Prcp_m = mean(Prcp))

coef_mod_on[[i]] <-
  data.frame(as.list(coef(mod))) %>%    # to get both coefficients
  as_tibble() 
}

coef_mod[[i]] <- bind_rows(coef_mod)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome. We need a bit more information before someone can answer your question. You need to provide your data objects (`stats`, `clim`, `ann`). For each of these you could paste the output of dput().